# How to convert magnitude to dB in matlab

Tags: matlab, magnitude

I exported a diagram from FDTD simulation, and now I want to change the magnitude to dB, here is the exported codes:

```
ax1 = axes; 

plot(lum.x0,lum.y0)

set(ax1, 'XLim', [1.49806e-06 1.60194e-06])

set(ax1, 'YLim', [-0.0232806 1.22328])

set(ax1,'XGrid', 'on')

set(ax1,'YGrid', 'on')
```

and the ploted spectrum is shown below
[image]

I just wondering how to convert the magnitude to dB?
I know there is a function called mag2dB, but i just dont know how to use it.
any help would be very appreciate.

Comment: try `semilogy(lum.x0,lum.y0)` FYI, there is also `semilogx()`

Answer (score 1):

```
valueInDB = 10*log10(magnitude.*conj(magnitude));
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct conversion from magnitude to dB is done by $20\text{log}_{10}\big(|x|\big)$.

I will highlight the parallel to Hilmar's answer by saying that the conversion from power to dB is done by $10\text{log}_{10}\big(|x|^2\big)$, so by following Hilmar you do $10\text{log}_{10}\big(xx^*\big)=10\text{log}_{10}\big(|x|^2 \big)$ which can be simplified to $20\text{log}_{10}\big(|x| \big)$.

MATLAB has a function `mag2db` which accomplishes this conversion, or you can simply do `20*log10(abs(lum.y0))`.

```
ax1 = axes; 

plot(lum.x0, mag2db(lum.y0))

set(ax1, 'XLim', [1.49806e-06 1.60194e-06])

set(ax1, 'YLim', [-0.0232806 1.22328])

set(ax1,'XGrid', 'on')

set(ax1,'YGrid', 'on')
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help!